# Sort, Filter and custom template column in TreeList

Tags: telerik, blazor, treelist

I am using TreeList and a custom template on a column to display user avatar. I also need to sort and filter on this column. However when combine all of these features (sort and filter) on a template column, it doesn't work. There are 2 issues:

- When disable sort, the filtering doesnt work
- *When enable sort, the filtering works but the sorting throw error: "Failed to compare two elements in the array."* --> This issue is already resolved as below comment.

Is there any work around solution for this? I am using UI for Blazor 3.0.1

```
<TelerikTreeList Data="@Tasks"
                 IdField="Id"
                 ParentIdField="ParentId"
                 Sortable="true"
                 SortMode="@SortMode.Single"
                 FilterMode="@TreeListFilterMode.FilterMenu">

    <TreeListColumns>

        @*when disable sort, the filtering doesnt work*@
        <TreeListColumn Field="Owner" FieldType="@typeof(Avatar)" Title="Owner" Sortable="false"
                        FilterMenuType="@FilterMenuType.CheckBoxList">
            <Template>
                @{
                    var item = context as TaskItem;
                    <MyAvatar Avatar="item.Owner"></MyAvatar>
                }
            </Template>
        </TreeListColumn>

        @*when enable sort, the filter works but the sorting throw error*@
        <TreeListColumn Field="Owner" FieldType="@typeof(Avatar)" Title="Owner" Sortable="true"
                        FilterMenuType="@FilterMenuType.CheckBoxList">
            <Template>
                @{
                    var item = context as TaskItem;
                    <MyAvatar Avatar="item.Owner"></MyAvatar >
                }
            </Template>
        </TreeListColumn>

    </TreeListColumns>
</TelerikTreeList>
```

---

Updated snipped: https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/mQuxlWkD32B5eGay33

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `Field` name is a primitive (value) type and not a full object. This is the field of the model used for filter and sort. Then, either remove the `FieldType`, or set it to the type of the `Owner` field, not to a different field.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your suggestion helps me to fix second issue. The first issue still happens: When disable sort, the filtering doesnt work, it doesnt show the filter icon. <TreeListColumn Field="Owner.Name" Title="Owner" Sortable="false">

Comment: That's odd. Make a repl and update your post https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/

Comment: @Radko has just help to create the snippet https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/mQuxlWkD32B5eGay33. In the 2nd column, the filter works when we set  Sortable="true" but it doesnt work when Sortable="false"

Comment: Might be, are you also taking to the Telerik support about it?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you actually want to bind the columns to the underlying primitive type you would like the comparison to be based on, rather than the `Avatar` object itself? To do that, you would like to update the `Field` and `FieldType` parameters to the appropriate nested property and type.

I've created a REPL snippet that demonstrates this (note I've added some dummy classes as they were missing from the initial snippet): https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/mQuxlWkD32B5eGay33

Comment: Thank you for your snipped. When I set Sortable="false" in 2nd column, the filter icon disappear. That is the problem. I think this is Telerik blazor issue.